# using Angular2 typescript component inside another navigated component

Tags: typescript, angular

I have two Angular2 components, a "Main" and "Another". From "Main", i'm navigating to "Another" which in its template has references to other components such as following template example:

```
<div>
    Some other templates and HTML...
    <person>Loading person...</person>
</div>
```

The issue is that the `person` component has to be bootstrapped if used in that way, however bootstrapping it will cause the selector match error. This makes sense as the HTML template hasn't rendered yet.

How is it possible to achieve this?

**Update**

Here is a sample code:

**Main**

```
import {Component, provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, Router, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

import {Another} from './Another';

@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/Another', name: 'Another', component: Another}
])
@Component({
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
    selector: 'Main',
    template:
    '<div>
        <button type="button" (click)="navigate()">Navigate</button>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>'
})
export class Main {
    constructor(private _router: Router) { }

    navigate() {
        this._router.navigate(['Another']);
    }
}
```

**Another**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'Another',
    template:
    '<div>
        <h1>i'm another!</h1>

        <!-- how do I use this here? -->
        <person>Loading person...</person>
    </div>'
})
export class Another {

}
```

**Person**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'person',
    template:
    '<div
        <h1>i'm person!</h1>
    </div>'
})
export class Person {

}
```

Again, if I bootstrap `person` at root component i'll get 'selector didn't match element' error.

**Update 2**

Adding `directives: [Person]` to "Another" component will result in following error: "Expected to not be in Angular Zone, but it is!", but the template for 'person' does render.

Comment: could you post your code?

Comment: @VadimSentyaev Updated.

Comment: Same problem here but when I dynamically render another component into my root component. Have you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I properly understand what you want to do, try this.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Person} from 'path-to-person-component';

@Component({
    selector: 'Another',
    template:
    '<div>
        <h1>i'm another!</h1>

        <!-- how do I use this here? -->
        <person>Loading person...</person>
    </div>',
    directives: [Person]
})
export class Another {

}
```

Comment: It does render now, but also throws this error "Expected to not be in Angular Zone, but it is!"

Comment: Same problem here, have you find any solution ?

Comment: @ChristopheGigax Person component is inside About component in plunker I've provided

Comment: Thanks ! All is about the NgModule, right ? it centralize all declarations, so it can manage properly components